# AS3 Air Android App That Loads SWF From URL

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash

I mean to create a android air app that does nothing more than load an external swf from a server, which will be the real app, all functions will be contained there, so anytime the user launches their app, they have the most recent version.

I have not seen any information about anyone doing this, but it seems an intuitive and obvious strategy to me.

I am concerned about a few things:

1. Will the Android device cache the swf and operate in the event the device is not connected to the internet?
2. Will all my functions within the swf be self contained or do I need to reference all objects with the container apk in mind? (_root.myObject wont work running in the apk, but _root.externalSWF.myObject will?)
3. I am assuming the external swf must be coded in AS3, or maybe not since its self contained? (This would rock, I code in AS2 intuitively and struggle with AS3)

Thanks in advance for any helpful response!

Answer (score 0):

1. The Android device will not cache the swf.  Perhaps you should build that in as a functionality yourself.
2. The swf can be self contained.  You do not need to reference the container.
3. According to [this](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3854739) post, AS2 is not supported on AIR for mobile.